# PDO mysql display with COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to obtain the number of determinated task types, but it gives me error: **Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Company_Name)
FROM salesplus WHERE `Task_Type` = 'Form Sent'
AND `Consultant_name` = 'Name Surname'");

$statement->execute();
$result=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($result as $row){
echo $row->Task_Type;
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works... try (to get count of exact task):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Company_Name FROM salesplus WHERE `Task_Type` = 'Form Sent' AND `Consultant_name` = 'Name Surname') as s
```

Or better (get list of companies and count of selected tasks for each company):

```
SELECT `Company_Name`,count(*) as count FROM salesplus WHERE `Task_Type` = 'Form Sent' AND `Consultant_name` = 'Name Surname' GROUP BY `Company_Name`
```

Comment: the end was cut ... as s.... could you please edit it? btw, thank you so much for such a quick answer :)

Comment: it wasn't ... mysql demands to name subselects... I named it `s` ... what are you trying to get anyway? gave you two solutions...

Comment: The first one is the one that I wanted :) Im super happy, thanks !